# Fetching FaultException.Detail.ErrorCode and FaultException.Detail.Message

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am having a program. If an exception occurs, I print the exception message in a cell in my excel sheet. Can I print the FaultException.Detail.ErrorCode and FaultException.Detail.Message?
How can I fetch these two things and print it??
Am posting a sample code

```
public int CreateTask(int row)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invoking CreateTask method");
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                m_taskID = taskClient.CreateTask(m_tInstance);
                Console.WriteLine("Task create successfully:ID=" + m_taskID.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");

                ExcelRecorder(null, row);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                
                ExcelRecorder(ex.Message, row);
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
            return m_taskID;
        }
```

How can I modify the ExcelRecorder() method such that FaultException.Detail.ErrorCode and FaultException.Detail.Message can be fetched?

Comment: How do we know what is the current code of your ExcelRecorder is!?

Comment: i just want to know how to fetch those two things? In excelrecorder(), all i do is just print the ex.message in a cell in an excel shete in my drive. thats it.

Comment: You asking `How can I modify` thats why Iam asking for code. Just cast Exception to FaltException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this clause above your existing `catch` clause:

```
        catch (FaultException<COMException> fex)
        {                
            string msg = fex.Detail.Message;
            string code = fex.Detail.ErrorCode.ToString();
            ExcelRecorder(String.Concat(msg, " - ", code), row);
        }
```

I presume that you need to catch exception `System.ServiceModel.FaultException<TDetail>` where `TDetail` is `COMException`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments, your question does need more code to properly answer, but from looking at what you have provided, it looks like your problem is that ExcelRecorder takes Exception, and not FaultException, so you can't access its Detail property to write to your spreadsheet.

Depending on whether ExcelRecorder is used elsewhere in your code, you could always modify the constructor of ExcelRecorder to take a FaultException object, or create a second ExcelRecorder constructor which takes a FaultException object and logs appropriately.

I really need to see the code of ExcelRecorder to help any further though.